# What is the 40 pin internal USB header used for?

Tags: usb, usb-3, usb-c

[image]

The USB 3.2 Gen 2 header (20 pins) is sometimes refereed to as a Type C header or Type E header, but I can not find any evidence of that being apart of the standard. There is also a 40 pin variant:

[image]

https://www.usb.org/sites/default/files/USB3p1_Front_Panel_CabCon_Implment_Doc_Rev1p1.pdf

What header is used for:

1. USB 2.0 High-Speed 0.48Gbps
2. USB 3.2 Gen 1×1 SuperSpeed 5Gbps
3. USB 3.2 Gen 2×1 SuperSpeed 10Gbps
4. USB 3.2 Gen 2x2 SuperSpeed 20Gbps
5. USB4 Gen 3×2 SuperSpeed 40Gbps
6. USB4 Gen 4 SuperSpeed 80Gbps

and what is the 40 pin connector used for?

Comment: If the USB specification says the only difference is the number of pins that must be the only difference. However, the fact they don’t have a diagram of the 40-pin, tells me that it’s not used. None of those except the top two are applicable to either the 20-pin or the 40-pin USB 3.1 Gen 1 (aka USB 3.2 Gen 1)header

Comment: @Ramhound, Does that mean the bottom 4 items on the list use the USB 3.2 Gen 2 header? (also that document says USB 3.1, could the USB4 standard take advantage of the 40 pins?)

Comment: "Could the USB4 standard take advantage of the 40 pins?" - No; The specification you provided ONLY applies to USB 3.1. USB 4 has its own specifications.  All your question can be answered by the USB 4 specification [here](https://www.usb.org/document-library/usb4r-specification-v20)

Comment: A grammar nit-pick on the question: "apart of the standard" should say "a part of the standard".

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The 40-pin header is an extension of the 20-pin count. The only difference between the two is the pin count.

20-pin supports one full feature Type-C port.

The 40-pin header was introduced to support two full feature Type-C ports.
See [Newnex USB Connector Type Guide](https://www.newnex.com/usb-connector-type-guide.php).

See [USB 3.1 / USB TYPE-CTM DESKTOP FRONT PANEL CABLE AND CONNECTOR IMPLEMENTATION DOCUMENT](https://www.usb.org/sites/default/files/USB3p1_Front_Panel_CabCon_Implment_Doc_Rev1p1.pdf) (PDF from [usb.org](https://www.usb.org)).

Comment: Can the USB 3.2 Gen 2 20 pin header support a USB4 Gen 4 SuperSpeed 80Gbps at full speed or does it require a different header?

Comment: @Brandon you could experiment, but please note USB 3.2 Gen 2 supports USB4 and speed is up to 10Gbps due to limitations of USB 3.2 Gen 2.  https://www.kensington.com/news/docking-connectivity-blog/exploring-usb4-thunderbolt-4-and-usb-c-3.2/#:~:text=Speed%3A%20USB%2DC%203.2%20Gen,%2DC%20Gen%202%20limits).

Comment: How are you supposed to get an 80Gbps port? I have only seen PCIe cards with it. Is there no header that supports 80Gbps in the standard?

Comment: You should ask that question to the community next. I answered your original question. Please vote up and mark it as answered if you think I did answer your original question..

Comment: Question asked here: https://superuser.com/q/1824982/401540

Comment: @Brandon i answered it. Please upvote or mark it as the answer if you think that it helps you in any way.