# What USB header supports USB4 Gen 4 SuperSpeed 80Gbps?

Tags: usb, usb-c

What USB header supports the full 80Gbps of USB4 Gen 4 SuperSpeed 80Gbps? I have only been able to find PCIe cards with the USB Type C ports but no headers. Can the [40 pin header](https://superuser.com/questions/1824974/what-is-the-40-pin-internal-usb-header-used-for/1824976?noredirect=1#comment2874445_1824976) do this or is there a different header for it?

- [USB4 Specification v2.0](https://www.usb.org/document-library/usb4r-specification-v20)

Comment: The chipset not necessary the header is what determines if USB 4 2.0 80 Gbps is supported.  I am unaware of any motherboard on that market that supports USB 4 2.0 80 Gbps. The appropriate chipsets to supports 80 Gbps were not even expected till after Q1 2024 in 2023.

Answer (score 1):

Existing hardware will probably be backward compatible, but speeds will be capped for older hardware. As a result, some [manufacturers](https://www.hirose.com/product/series/DF40) have began to market their hardware as "Supports USB4 Gen2", but speeds will not reach the maximum speed of USB4 Ver 2 80Gbps (or 120Gbps), if both hardware/devices do not natively support USB4 Ver2. Also, according to [this](https://www.keysight.com/blogs/en/tech/bench/2022/11/08/usb-80gbps-whats-new-in-usb4-version-2), the USB4 Version 2 standard is still under compliance test specification, so headers information and details are not yet available as of todays date. The USB4 Ver 2 is the specification that supports up to [120 Gbps](https://www.onlogic.com/company/io-hub/usb-type-c-and-usb-3-1-explained/#:%7E:text=USB%2010%20Gbps%3A%20The%20specification,A%20and%20USB%2DC%20connectors) (80Gbps one-way and 40Gbps the other way) if configured asymmetrically. One can expect manufacturers may be close to releasing native USB4 80Gbps (or 120Gbps) capable hardware/devices later in 2024.

.